# Using Docker Containers for my development environment

Tags: docker

With Docker, is this procedure possible? If so, how can I do that?

1. Create a CMake Container A.
2. Create a [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/build-essential) (gcc, headers, etc.) Container B.
3. Use A for my project folder, then use B for compiling my project. In this case, A accesses the Container B as A is trying to find files regarding to B.

I found out that A works with my project and B also does, (A and B have Bind Volume to my project and I run `docker exec` command) but I have no idea how to have A access B. So I've been making a big Container where all tools (CMake, build-essential, etc.) are installed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good practice (to my pov) using a container for the build and another one for your run.
This is an exemple from oslandia's QGIS build : https://github.com/Oslandia/docker-qgis

In this configuration, there is no real pb using a "big" image with lot of tools, since you will not  us it for runtime purpose: its only purpose is to generate your binaries.

Also you can consider doing the same in a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) : your first step would be the "build essentials", and then you will use it through a CMake step... and so on. This is how you make "A and B communicate" => you use B in A that way.

En exemple could be zooproject build : http://zoo-project.org/trac/browser/trunk/Dockerfile

But in this case, you Dockerfile will mix build and run instructions... this may not be a pb, but I like to separate build from run : it's only up to you.
Anyway, you can still separate the run and the build in two containers : the first one will still be multistage.